# Shifting a variable up in R data frame with respect to another variable

Tags: r

I have a data.frame:

```
ID <-c(2,2,2,2,3,3,5,5)
Pur<-c(0,1,2,3,1,2,4,5)
df<-data.frame(ID,Pur)
```

I would like to push the `Pur` up for each `ID` to get the `up.Pur` as follows:

```
 ID Pur up.Pur
 2   0   1
 2   1   2
 2   2   3
 2   3   NA
 3   1   2
 3   2   NA
 5   4   5
 5   5   NA
```

Would appreciate your help with this.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, but `ave(df$Pur, df$ID, FUN=function(x) c(NA,tail(x,-1)) )` should do it. Otherwise there are `lead()` and `shift()` functions in `dplyr` or `data.table` respectively.

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail! Couldn't  found any questions to do it in respect to a grouping variable. I might have missed, though. Happy to remove the question if you know a similar one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `shift` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, up.Pur := shift(Pur, type = "lead"), by = ID]
df
#   ID Pur up.Pur
#1:  2   0      1
#2:  2   1      2
#3:  2   2      3
#4:  2   3     NA
#5:  3   1      2
#6:  3   2     NA
#7:  5   4      5
#8:  5   5     NA
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `dplyr` approach

```
library(dplyr)

ID <-c(2,2,2,2,3,3,5,5)
Pur<-c(0,1,2,3,1,2,4,5)
df<-data.frame(ID,Pur)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(up.Pur = lead(Pur)) 

# Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
# Groups: ID [3]
# 
#       ID   Pur   up.Pur
# <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     2     0      1
# 2     2     1      2
# 3     2     2      3
# 4     2     3     NA
# 5     3     1      2
# 6     3     2     NA
# 7     5     4      5
# 8     5     5     NA
```

For completeness, I've added a base R approach, just in case you don't feel like installing any packages.

```
dfList = split(df, ID)

dfList = lapply(dfList, function(x){
  x$up.Pur = c(x$Pur[-1], NA)
  return(x)
})

unsplit(dfList, ID)

#   ID Pur up.Pur
# 1  2   0      1
# 2  2   1      2
# 3  2   2      3
# 4  2   3     NA
# 5  3   1      2
# 6  3   2     NA
# 7  5   4      5
# 8  5   5     NA
```